# Dynamically move and initialize Form elements created by the Form Designer during form startup

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using the Visual Studio Form Designer to initially lay out a form for my Windows desktop application. Here is a snippet of the content of my auto-generated `InitializeComponent()` method for that form:

```cs
// ...
this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
this.Name = "Form1";
this.Text = "Form1 Title";
this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
this.toolStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
this.toolStrip1.PerformLayout();
// ...
```

What I would like to do is inject a procedure that moves, resizes and initializes the form and several of its controls during the startup process. And I believe that the ideal place to do this is immediately prior to the first call to `ResumeLayout()`.

Conveniently, I found that I am able to override the [`Text Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.text%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of my form:

```cs
public override String Text
{
    set
    {
        if (!this.formInitialized)
        {
            DoSpecialFormInitialization();
            this.formInitialized = true;
        }

        base.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Although I am finding that this approach is indeed working, it leaves me feeling that there may be a better way to achieve my goal. Is there a better approach, preferably one that does not require significantly more effort?

**Update:** As I indicated in a comment in response to the answer by @Grant Winney, I know I can do my initialization in the form constructor, following the call to `InitializeComponent()`. But I am seeking to avoid repeating all of the calls to `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` (see internals of `InitializeComponent()`) because I believe this degrades performance and could lead to future maintenance headaches.

Unfortunately, it is *not* sufficient to simply invoke `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` on just the parent form. Here is information as to why from [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163630.aspx#S5) (see third paragraph) referenced by @Grant:

> Remember that SuspendLayout only prevents Layout events from being
>   performed for that particular control. If controls are added to a
>   panel, for example, SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout must be called for
>   the panel and not for the parent form.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

1. You could call a method from your constructor to move the controls around. That seems less "hacky", since it's not depending on a side-effect of some other property on the form being set.
   *(Also, if someone modifies the code in the future to change the window text at runtime, they're going to inadvertently run your initialization code again.)*

   ```
   public class MyForm : Form
   {
       public MyForm()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           DoSpecialFormInitialization();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use this sparingly. Maintenance becomes really difficult when a form looks one way in the designer, and then one of 12 different ways at runtime.

Comment: **1.** Yes, this was the first approach that I tried. However, I found that I needed to repeat all of the calls to `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` that appear in `InitializeComponent()`. **2.** My form has several panels, only one of which is visible at any given time. In the designer, I laid out all of the panels and then collapse the main form and display the first panel on startup.

Comment: More: Each of the panels occupies the same location on the form. What I am doing is kind of like a wizard. I have `TreeView` on the left that drives the rest of the form. Clicking on a node in the `TreeView` displays a panel associated with that particular type of node.

Comment: Yes, minimizing future maintenance and the potential "element of surprise" is foremost in my mind! One possibility, of course, would be to drop the use of the Designer altogether and build the form entirely in a programmatic fashion. But I used the Designer because I believe it saved me a lot of work!

Comment: **1.** With respect to my form, `InitializeComponent()` suspends and resumes all of the following controls: Form, Panel, GroupBox, MenuStrip, ToolStrip and StatusStrip. This lead be to believe that suspending and resuming just the parent form itself may not be sufficient. But is it? **2.** Good point! But I should be able to allow the special processing to take place only once by introducing a private `Boolean` member variable on my form, say `m_FormInitialized`.

Comment: **1.** Thanks much for the link. **2.** Agreed. As I always do in situations like this, I have added ample comments to my code saying that my approach is a bit of a hack along with words that indicate my motivation for it. Of course, I'm also standing by for other answers that may be forthcoming. :-)